# How to get a Tikz arrow to point to different parts of a text node?

Tags: tikz-arrows, arrows, nodes, node-connections

[image]

I essentially wish to create this effect, where I have to nodes connected by an arrow and I can freely adjust the starting point and ending point of the arrow.

I have no idea which option to use. I see that by default I have the anchor option, but this only give me one direction.

Can someone provide a small example? Much thanks!

Comment: I think it would be helpful if you provide an *MWE* in order to reduce guesswork.

Comment: MWE: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/

Comment: Suppose you have nodes called `A` and `B` and wish to join them with an arrow. You can use the default and let `tikz` work out which parts to join using `\draw[->] (A) -- (B);`. If this is unsatisfactory you can tell it which parts of the node to join. For example, if you want to join the top right hand corner of `A` to the middle left of `B` then you could use `\draw[->] (A.north east) -- (B.west);`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture]
\node at (0,0) {This letter is \subnode{Ti}{T}};
\node at (3,1.5) {\subnode{Tf}{T}his is a Cat};
\draw[->, shorten <=1pt] (Ti) -- (Tf);

\node at (0,2) {This letter is \subnode{Ci}{C}};
\node at (3,3.5) {This is a \subnode{Cf}{C}at};
\draw[->] (Ci) -- (Cf);

\node at (0,4) {This letter is \subnode{ai}{a}};
\node at (3,5.5) {This is \subnode{af}{a} Cat};
\draw[->] (ai) -- (af);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: tikzmarknode isn't meant to be used inside a node as that leads to nesting tikz pictures. I would recommend using `\subnode` here (also from the tikzmark package) as it was designed for exactly this purpose

Comment: @Andrew Stacey You are right! Thank you for the correction. I already fixed this.